# Problems with memory kill limits for YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have problem with understanding YARN configuration.
I have such lines in yarn/mapreduce configs:

```
<name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
<value>2048</value>

<name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
<value>1024</value>

<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
<value>2.1</value>
```

[Here](https://discuss.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201462036-MapReduce-YARN-Memory-Parameters) is written:

> By default ("yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio") is set to 2.1.  This means that a map or reduce container can allocate up to 2.1 times the ("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb") or ("mapreduce.map.memory.mb")  of virtual memory before the NM will kill the container.

When NodeManager will kill my container?
When a whole container reaches 2048MB*2.1=4300,8MB? Or 1024MB*2.1=2150,4MB

Can i get some better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Each Mapper and Reducer runs in its own separate container (containers are not shared between Mappers and Reducers, unless it is a Uber job. Check about Uber mode here: [What is the purpose of "uber mode" in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284237/what-is-the-purpose-of-uber-mode-in-hadoop)).

Typically, memory requirements for a Mapper and a Reducer differ.

Hence, there are different configuration parameters for Mapper (`mapreduce.map.memory.mb`) and Reducer (`mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb`).

So, as per the settings in your `yarn-site.xml`, virtual memory limits for Mapper and Redcuer are:

```
Mapper limit: 2048 * 2.1 = 4300.8 MB

Reducer limit: 1024 * 2.1 = 2150.4 MB
```

In short, Mappers and Reducers have different memory settings and limits.